# php-osx not loading mcrypt.so on Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, libtomcrypt

Tried to run `php --version` this is what i got

```
/usr/local/php5-5.6.1-20141004-104642/bin/php --version
```

> PHP Warning:
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library `'/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so'`
> `- dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so, 9):`
>
> Library not loaded: `/usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib`
>
> Referenced from:  `/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so`
> Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this site https://coderwall.com/p/8pajlg you need to install libtool via Homebrew:

```
brew install libtool --universal
brew link libtool
```

Answer (score 2):

Yosemite use php55.
via Macports:

```
sudo port install php54-mcrypt
```

in php.ini

```
extension=/opt/local/lib/php55/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to use `sudo port install php55-mcrypt`